# filter/get entity in google app engine to validate if it exists or not

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i have the following model in google app engine:

```
class CustomUsers(db.Model):
    cuid = db.StringProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    email = db.StringProperty()
    bday = db.StringProperty()
```

now given a `cuid` i just want to check if he is present in the high replication data store. 
in my views i write the following, but eventually get an 500 error:

```
usr_prev = CustomUsers.all().filter('cuid =', request.POST['id'])
if(not usr_prev):
    logging.info("this user does not exist")
else:
    logging.info("user exists")
```

but this gives me an error. How shall i do it?
(Do not consider any importing issues.)

Comment: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: write() argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not int
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~upfbapp2012/1.356582092823580999/django_bootstrap.py", line 62, in main
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 98, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 119, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    sys.stdout.write(data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go like this to see:

```
query = Users.all()
cnt = query.filter('id =', user_id).count()
logging.info(cnt)
return int(cnt)
```

once this is done, seems you are using django with app engine,  as per the error you are not returning string response.  you might want to return 
`return HttpResponse("1")` instead of `return HttpResponse(1)`

Answer (score 0):

"500 errors" don't exist in isolation. They actually report useful information, either on the debug page or in the logs. I'd guess that your logs show that `request.POST` has no element `id`, but that is just a guess.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i just wanted a way to see if a user corresponding to the user id exists in the database. There is no issue with post etc.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have assigned a query object to usr_prev. You need to execute the query. I think Query.count(1) function should do it.

However, this may not be related to the 500 error.